# clearTimeout prevents setTimeout from running

Tags: javascript, html, settimeout

```
  const func = () => {
    const id = setTimeout(() => {
      //do something with an element
    }, 300);
    return id;
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const id = func();
    return () => clearTimeout(id);
  }, [click]);
```

When I click too fast, which is the trigger to the `useEffect`, it could cause the function passed to setTimeout to not be runned.

What is the problem?

Is the following alternative solution just as good?

```
  const func = () => {
    const id = setTimeout(() => {
      if (element is stilled defined) {
      // do something  
      }
    }, 300);
    return id;
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    func();
  }, [click]);
```

Comment: Are you making a sort of simple throttle function?

Comment: not sure what you mean by throttle.

Comment: Throttle/Debounce, methods to limit how often a function is invoked. Is this what you are trying to do? If `func` is invoked again within 300ms it will clear the previous timeout and start a new one.

Comment: ah, do you mean that there can only be one instance of a clearTimeout in existence at a particular range of time in a javascript program?

Comment: Yes, if you clear the previous one. Are you just wanting to delay each callback invocation by 300ms?

Comment: what is `click`? it looks like you need to check if click !== null in that case.

Comment: "*When I click too fast, which is the trigger to the `useEffect`*" - something is wrong with that. You don't need to use `useEffect` for effects caused by listeners. Can you show us the whole component please?

Comment: @free_lions_n_tigers_from_cages "*do you mean that there can only be one instance of a clearTimeout in existence*" - no, but there can only be one effect from a `useEffect` be active at the same time (per component).

Comment: The use `useEffect` is to trigger an animation. First it scales a component to `transform = scale(2)` and then calls a setTimeout to be run 100ms seconds later to scale it back to normal size. If a useEffect is not needed for these kind of things, how can it be done?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your code correctly it seems you are wanting to delay a callback function by some delta. I suggest using a React ref to track an array of running timers. When the function is invoked, add the new timeout id to this array, when the timeout expires clear it from the array. Use an onUnmount useEffect to cleanup any running timeouts.

```
const timeoutRef = useRef([]);

const func = () => {
  const id = setTimeout(() => {
    //do something with an element
    dequeueCallback(id);
  }, 3000);
  enqueueCallback(id);
};

const enqueueCallback = (id) => {
  timeoutRef.current.push(id);
};
const dequeueCallback = (id) => {
  timeoutRef.current = timeoutRef.current.filter((el) => el !== id);
};

useEffect(() => {
  // clear any running timeouts upon unmount
  return () => {
    timeoutRef.current.forEach(clearTimeout);
  };
}, []);
```

### Demo

[image: Edit cleartimeout-prevents-settimeout-from-running]

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve this issue by cleanup function, the cleanup function will trigger when the effect rerender is trigger, so you can put what is must happen before any action, so that, the solution will just by this:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(myEvent);
    // You can add condtion here and above of cleaner
    const timer = setTimeout(() => {
      if(myEvent !== null){// Internal contion
        alert("HI MAN");
      }
    }, 2000);

    return () => clearTimeout(timer);// This is important part
  }, [myEvent]);
```

check this example:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [myEvent, setMyEvent] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(myEvent);
    
    const timer = setTimeout(() => {
      if(myEvent !== null){
        alert("HI MAN");
      }
    }, 2000);

    return () => clearTimeout(timer);
  }, [myEvent]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={() => {
        setMyEvent(Math.random);
      }}>test</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

And this is [URL Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/billowing-brook-jjk04?file=/src/App.js).

React Referance:
[React Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)